# "Invalid Application. Delete?" only when compiled with a Nokia SDK

Tags: java-me, sdk, nokia, nfc

I'm developing a piece of software for my University and am currently attempting to implement NFC functionality which requires me to move from my standard Sun wireless tool-kit platform (implemented through [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans)) to a Nokia platform (also implemented through NetBeans).

The problem is, whenever I compile the code with the Nokia platform implementation and run the program, on the Nokia phone I have or in the emulator, the phone displays a box stating "Invalid Application. Delete?" with a yes/no answer. This stops the installation of the application. The strange part is that if I compile the exact same code with the Sun platform implementation it runs without any issues on the Nokia phone. I have tried this with two different Nokia SDKs (the Series 40 Nokia 6212 NFC SDK and the Series 40 5th Edition SDK) with the same results.

What is the Nokia SDK doing differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of discrepancy between a project created using a Sun platform and a project created in a Nokia platform.

Although the original program, initially created with the Sun platform, compiled with the Nokia platform caused the application to be invalid, when I created a new project from scratch using the Nokia platform and just copied the source of the original program over the program worked. There is no discernible difference in the [JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28file_format%29)/manifest files between the two.

Comment: if by Nokia platform you mean Nokia SDK then there may be a difference in Java version and APIs. I recently noticed that Nokia SDK allows vectors, enums etc usage, which is not possible with J2ME because it is based on Java 1.3. One quick test would be to see if there are any differences in the included jars.

Comment: Indeed it does seem to be the case but you would assume that both being sdk's designed to produce code for the same language that they would not have such a fundamental difference.


P.S.
you can use enums (http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) and vectors (http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) in j2me, perhaps you are thinking of an older implementation

Answer (score 1):

If you've copied source code, you may have not copied the "manifest.midlets", i.e. tells the OS which "forms" to create.  You'll usually find this in the project properties.

(e.g. in NetBeans IDE - Application Descriptor, "Midlets" tab - it shouldn't be empty).

Comment: No it doesn't cause a compiler error - as it's the OS that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the following attributes (key:value pairs) are in the JAD file and also the manifest file in the JAR file:

1. MIDlet-Name
2. MIDlet-Version
3. MIDlet-Vendor
4. MIDlet-Jar-URL
5. MIDlet-Jar-Size

Comment: The program is being compiled via net-beans so both the jad and the manifest are automatically created, I double checked that these things were there and they are.